# If I include the Nav tag,nothing else is displayed on the screen on chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The Bootstrap used works perfectly fine on Chrome but not on Firefox, but it doesn't show "Hi Hello" in Chrome but it does show it in Firefox.

In fact it doesn't recognize anything after the nav code. I want a fixed to top nav bar.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <link href="C:/Users/Dhruv/Desktop/bootstrap/bootstrap-3-Offline-Docs-master/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="one" >
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container" style="background:#212124;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign In</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Explore</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Create</button>
                    <div style="float:right;">
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div>
                <p>Hi</p>
                hello
            </div>
        </header>
        <script src="C:/Users/Dhruv/Desktop/bootstrap/Bootstrap-3-Offline-Docs-master/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="C:/Users/Dhruv/Desktop/bootstrap/Bootstrap-3-Offline-Docs-master/dist/js/Bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/holder.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/application.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use relative paths, and not absolute to reference the css.

Comment: Duplicate `</head>` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using 'float: right' on a div, but not clearing the floats before closing the parent div... So it's likely that the hi/hello text is actually under the navbar somewhere...

If you're floating elements, you need to add

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

after the last floating div closes, and you would set

```
.clear { clear:both; }
```

in your styles